# Why is the texture not appearing on the model

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to see what distortion I have on these UV's, I applied the default grid pattern in the UVs but it is not appearing on the model. Does anyone know why?[image]

Comment: maybe if you chose the textured shading option... you're in solid mode

Comment: Did you customize the display of textures on the material? Оr you probably did not turn on texture mapping.

Comment: Cool... now it's all black.

Comment: Maybe? I am new, how would I check?

Comment: Okay you must to open window with materials. And you must to turn Cycles render in top menu

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not sure what that means.

Comment: ok in that case I'll give you a link to the tutorial that will help you in this matter. https://youtu.be/9PJL0eAuZ_E

Comment: Awesome thank you, that video helped.I am not use to the lighting in this coming from MAYA. Turns out the light was just out of position and was not casting enough for the image to appear. THANK YOU AGAIN!!

Answer (score 1):

Imho you could benefit doing some more research (ie: https://www.blender.org/manual/) before posting that nothing works...

solid mode:

[image]

textured mode:

[image]